# Can anyone tell me how to insert this with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]

I know to insert the text and the buttons , i just don't understand those two black images or whatever they are . Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than that. Currently the answer could be: `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfa17.png">` :p

Comment: Please provide more details of what you want to do and provide a code snippet of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make a guess. The black images are placeholders (because everything else you have looks like placeholders). I'm guessing you are searching for the CSS to make the frames around the images and perhaps how to "float" them on top of each other?

```css
.float-stuff-relative-to-this-div {
  position: relative;
}
.image-frame{
  border: 5px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px black;
}
.floaty-float{
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  /* Puts it behind stuff with higher z-index (default is 0) */
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="float-stuff-relative-to-this-div">
  <img class="image-frame" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/000000/000000">
  <img class="image-frame floaty-float" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/000000/000000">
</div>
```

Comment: Dont make a guess, @fitim is asking about the two black images in the screenshot, that is attached in the link given in the question. And by the way wrong guess.

Comment: And as I said, those are placeholders. That part of the question needs no guessing. But fine, I edited my placeholders to be black as well and am trying my hardest to not roll my eyes.

Comment: Nah I make mistakes all the time. Sorry for being snarky.

Comment: Its okay, pros like you let me learn a lot, and you have so much reputation, meaning you are one most knowledgeable persons around.

Comment: My roll-eye comment was overboard, my apology was sincere and I really thought you were calling me out for using the wrong color of my placeholders, which I in that moment thought was the epitome of pettiness.

Comment: no, its fine.. its cool bro.. by the way your answer helped, I always thought, how can we do that, but I cant put up a question for that. They have revoked those rights. So now I answer only. I am sorry too if my comment was a bit rude.